# Unified Switching between Keyboard Layouts in Various OSs

Tags: keyboard, vmware

I have a Mac with VMWare installed and run Windows- and Ubuntu-powered virtual machines there. The problem is that in each of the operating systems I have to use different keys to switch between keyboard layouts (English->German->Russian).

Does anybody know whether there is some way to unify the layout switching key combination in all the OSs? For instance switching the layouts using Apple/Windows key and Space Bar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, should be possible. You just need to unify your keyboard shortcuts in each OS.

For OS X it's in "System Preferences" → "Keyboard"/"Keyboard Shortcuts" for Snowleopard it's in "Keyboard & Text Input" on the left side and then you enter your desired shortcut by clicking on the assigned shortcut and pressing the combination you want.

Note that <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> is usually assigned to Spotlight search, so you would need to change that too.

[image: select_input_source]

And I think you know how to change it in Windows and Ubuntu, or you're able to find out - right ?